# Problems in replacing symbol to nothing

Tags: javascript

How can I solve this error, which i keep getting, here it is:

> TypeError: date.replace is not a function
>
> date = date.replace("*", "");

And this is all code:

```
var date = cellElement.innerHTML.split("/");
date = date.replace("*", "");
alert(date);
```

cellElement.innerHTML looks like this

> 2015/Rgs/01*

**Something is wrong with that replace.**

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `date` is an **array**, you cannot use `string` methods on it. When you use `split()` on string, `array` is returned.

To replace `*` symbol from string, you need to first `replace` it and then `split` it by `/`.

```
var date = cellElement.innerHTML.replace("*", "").split("/");
alert(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong type of variable.

method replace works only with type String.

try this:

```
var date = cellElement.innerHTML.split("/");
var date2string = date.toString();
date = date2string.replace("*", "");
```

or:

```
var date = cellElement.innerHTML.replace("*","");
var result = date.split("/");
alert(result);
```